# Viewing a Personal Campaign Page before approval

Tags: personal-campaign-pages

We've recently started using the PCP feature, and all of our supporters' PCPs must be approved. However, I haven't found a way to view/edit the PCP they have created *before* approval, which seems important. When Managing PCPs, unapproved pages are greyed out, and clicking on Edit takes me to the public contribution page with the error that the PCP isn't available.

Is there something I'm missing? Shouldn't admins be able to view before approval?

Joomla 3.7.5, Civi 4.7.21

Answer (score 2):

You *should* be able to view the page before approving it. (I just tried this on CiviCRM 4.7.24 by disabling a page and then viewing it. It worked for me.)

My guess is that your user does not have the necessary permissions to view unapproved PCPs. From looking [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/0f03f337533bb76fb7fe6dcc25cdd624daef24f3/CRM/PCP/Page/PCPInfo.php#L57), it appears that **you need the "Administer CiviCRM" permission**. If you're using Drupal, you can grant this permission by visiting `/admin/people/permissions`. Steps vary on other CMS platforms.

Comment: Unfortunately, permissions are definitely not the problem, as it happens when I am logged in as a superuser. I'll add my CMS/Civi versions to the question.

Comment: @PhilMoriceBrubaker I'd like to help you resolve this, but I'll need to be able to reproduce the behavior you're experiencing. Can you try to reproduce it on a [public demo site](https://civicrm.org/demo)? If you want to chat more about this, find me in the [User Support chat room](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/user-support) by writing a message tagged with `@seanmadsen`.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. On the Joomla demo site, it worked as I would expect it to work. But, that is Civi 4.6, not 4.7, on Joomla 3.6. I seem to remember at some point in a recent Joomla upgrade (maybe to 3.7) there was a change in how Joomla handled internal URLs which caused some errors like this. So far, the evidence suggests something similar to me - though it could be a specific server/installation problem.

Comment: I've now checked the URL possibility by taking an edit link for an Active PCP (/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/pcp/info&action=update&reset=1&id=1&context=dashboard  -- works fine), and replacing "id=1" with "id=2", the pcp id of a disabled PCP. This resolves to "/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=13" - which is the main Contribution page associated with the PCP. So, I think it is NOT the way that Joomla is handling the URL, otherwise the active page would also have problems, right?